# Display a new div after every number of records fetch from database in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a div for ads on a project I'm working on. I want the div to show after 8 records is fetch from the database.

My select statement:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE `username` = '$followe' OR `user_id` = ' $get_id' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15 ");
$newsCount = mysql_num_rows($query); // Count the output amount

if ($newsCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $user_post_id = $row["user_id"];
        $username = $row["username"];
        $text =     $row["texts"];
        $profile_pix = $row["profile_pix"];
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: @tadman thanks this is a problem i'm  facing current,i already have codes written in mysql,now i want tn switch,any advice please?

Comment: MySQL is the database. `mysql_query`, `mysqli` and PDO, among others, are all ways of *using* MySQL. As for your question, I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't even see a `<div>` when you're talking about that. You're missing a lot of code here. As another observation, **do not** jam closing braces on the end of lines like that. They should flow below so that the structure is clear. Indent properly, mistakes become more obvious. The `while` is nested inside the `if` here, they should be on different levels.

Comment: Any idea on how to switch to mysql queries to mysqli queries?

Comment: If you're going to re-write your code, to it with PDO. It's a much better interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a counter for your `while` loop and echo the HTML string when the counter is divisible by 8:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE `username` = '$followe' OR `user_id` = ' $get_id' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15 ");
    $newsCount = mysql_num_rows($query); // Count the output amount

    if ($newsCount > 0) {
        $rowcount=1;
        $divhtml = "<div></div>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
             if ($rowcount % 8 == 0) {
                 echo $divhtml;
             }
             $rowcount++;

             $id = $row["id"];
             $user_post_id = $row["user_id"];
             $username = $row["username"];
             $text =     $row["texts"];
             $profile_pix = $row["profile_pix"];
        }
    }
?>
```

You should change the content of variable $divhtml, with your own ad HTML.

Comment: This does it only on the 8th row. Not the 16th, etc.

Comment: @tadman original query is LIMIT 15 but it's not a big deal, i update code now

Comment: It's always best to provide a solution that's flexible, like every N rows on some arbitrary range. Really it's a minor difference that makes it way more useful.

Comment: @tadman it is right, just skipped it. Now code is updated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use an accumulator pattern such as this.

```
          $i = 0
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
              $i++;
              if(i == 8) {
                  // DO WHATEVER 
              }
              $id = $row["id"];
              $user_post_id = $row["user_id"];
              $username = $row["username"];
              $text =     $row["texts"];
              $profile_pix = $row["profile_pix"];
          }
```

Comment: This does it only on the 8th row. Not the 16th, etc.

Comment: @tadman that's what he asked for 'show the div on after 8 records' not 'show the div after each 8th record.' You would simply substitute `i == 8` for `i %8 == 0`